# This is a placeholder for the subdomain sometimes and some devices?

Tags: subdomain, digital-ocean

I just made the web site base on ruby on rails and host it at Digitalocean.
So my client want to use their subdomain from their old site.
(Their domain hosted on Godaddy.)

Then i set up everything and it works fine on all of my devices (mac air, iphone5 , iphone6 also and Windows labtop).

But sometimes when some of their staffs open the site they got the message like this

```
This is a placeholder for the subdomain xxx.yyy.com.
```

But I never faced this message

So how can I fix this?

Comment: First step to fixing something is understanding what exactly is broken. We don't have this info. And neither do you, it seems. So I suggest you liaise with their staff who see the problem, try reproducing it and find out what causes it. Then fixing it should be easy.

Comment: The problem is when i checked the website with them everything seem fine but when the same guy with their same device open the site in the other place without me then the problem came out. That make me have no idea how can i figure out the problem.

Answer (score -1):

in public_html edit or delete index.html